# Проблема с переносом массива int в argv[] для функции execv

Tags: c++, linux, процесс

Нужно передать массив переменной длины как аргумент вызываемой программы. Для этого использую функцию execv, т.к. там как раз аргументы передаются как массив указателей. Массив указателей формирую следующим образом:

```
char** argv = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char*)*(size+2));//size - размер int массива
argv[0] = "prog";
char buf [3];
for ( int j = 1; j < size+1; j++)
{
    sprintf(buf, "%d", array[(first + j - 1)]);//first - смещение в исходном int массиве
    argv[j] = buf;
}
argv[size+1] = NULL;
execv("prog", argv);
```

Проблема заключается в том, что в массив argv на место всех элементов числового массива записывается последний элемент этого массива, то есть: был числовой массив 1 4 3 5 7 6, а вызываемая программа получила массив 6 6 6 6 6 6. Вызываемая программа точно работает правильно, проблема именно в передаче в argv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну сами подумайте!

```
sprintf(buf, "%d", array[(first + j - 1)]); 
argv[j] = buf;
```

**Все** ваши `argv` хранят *один и тот же адрес* - `buf`! Который вы каждый раз перезаписываете.

Воспользуйтесь массивом типа

```
char buf[количество аргументов][максимальная длина];
```

Ну, или динамически размещаемым - типа

```
argv[j] = malloc(...)
sprintf(argv[j]...
```

Кстати, у вас же C++ - так почему `malloc`, а не `new`&?...

Comment: Действительно, проглядел, спасибо большое
А malloc осталась как привычка, до этого много на Си писал